# Gulp notify not working on successful cucumber steps

Tags: gulp, cucumberjs, gulp-notify

I am using `gulp-notify` to get notification of passing and failing cucumber steps.

The thing is that I only get notifications when it is failing, not when tests are passing.

No errors are thrown but the terminal shows passing tests, and I don't get any notification.

Here the contents of my Gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var cucumber = require('gulp-cucumber');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');

gulp.task('cucumber', function() {
    gulp.src('*features/*')
        .pipe(cucumber({
            'steps': '*features/step_definitions/*.js',
            'support': '*features/support/*.js'
        }))
        .on('error', notify.onError({
            title: 'Red',
            message: 'Your test(s) failed'
        }))
        .pipe(notify({
            title: 'Green',
            message: 'All tests passed (you can refactor)'
        }));

});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(['features/**/*.feature', 'features/**/*.js', 'script/**/*.js'], ['cucumber']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Any ideas what I could be missing?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working by calling directly `cucumberjs`, like this:

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const notifier = require('node-notifier');
const path = require('path');

gulp.task('cucumber', function() {
  const { exec } = require('child_process');
  exec('clear && node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
      if (error) {
          notifier.notify({
            title: 'Red',
            message: 'Your test(s) failed',
            icon: path.join(__dirname, 'failed.png')
          });
      } else {
          notifier.notify({
            title: 'Green',
            message: 'All tests passed (you can refactor)',
            icon: path.join(__dirname, 'passed.png')
          });
      }

      console.log(stdout);
      console.log(stderr);
  });
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(['features/**/*.js', 'script/**/*.js'], ['cucumber']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['cucumber', 'watch']);
```